# how to use where like in restful api codeigniter 4?

Tags: php, mysql, rest, query-builder, codeigniter-4

I'm making a reactjs that is connected to a restful api server using codeigniter 4. I want to only show the data where the field `username` and `full_name` contains a query string `q`

this is how my code looks like more or less:

```
<?php
namespace App\Controllers;

use CodeIgniter\RESTful\ResourceController;
use CodeIgniter\API\ResponseTrait;
use App\Models\UserModel;

class Users extends ResourceController
{
    use ResponseTrait;

    public function index()
    {
        $model = new UserModel();

        $data = [];

        // example uri: http://localhost:8080/users?q=asd
        $qs = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
        parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $_GET);
        $searchStr = empty($_GET['q']) ? '' : $_GET['q'];
        if ($searchStr)
        {
            $data = $model->group_start()
                            ->like('username', $searchStr)
                            ->or_like('nama', $searchStr)
                        ->group_end()
                        ->findAll();
        }
        else
        {
            $data = $model->findAll();
        }

        return $this->respond($data);
    }
}
```

when the search box in the react js app is empty, all the data is being shown correctly.. but when the search box is not empty, the `$data` returns an empty array.. is the problem around the `group_start()` part? how should I fix this?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **problem** is , your not using any wild card in your SQL query
this is a  [link](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp) to SQL **like** operation

also I don't think you don't need to pars **query string** from URL , just type `$_GET['q']`

in this line u had a mistake to :

```
$searchStr = empty($_GET['q']) ? '' : $_GET['q']);
```

the empty condition is true when u have q in your query .
just do it like blow :

```
$searchStr = $_GET['q'] ? $_GET['q'] : '' ;
```

sample : `$myString =  condition ?  true : false ;`

**here is how I don it :**
**Pay attention to the pattern line**

```
public function index()
    {
        $model = new UserModel();
        $data = [];
        $searchStr = $_GET['q'] ? $_GET['q'] : '' ;
        if ($searchStr)
        {
            $patern = '%'.$searchStr.'%'; // % char represent any char in before and after

            $data = $model->group_start()
                            ->like('username', $patern )
                            ->or_like('nama', $patern )
                        ->group_end()
                        ->findAll();
        }
        else
        {
            $data = $model->findAll();
        }
```

Comment: sorry, I have only been working with CodeIgniter 3 all this time. as I mentioned in the question, I need to find the data where it *contains* the search keyword so it doesn't have to be an *exact* match.. so if the keyword is 'one' then 'bone' and 'cone' should also be included in the result. I thought that's the purpose of `like`? and it doesn't use a wildcard in CI3

Comment: check out my new answer now @dapidmini

Comment: thank you. I've just found some more resource material and I found out that what you said before was already correct. those methods had been changed into `groupStart()` and `orLike()`. so I think your original answer had more important keypoints. in my opinion, the important keypoints are to use `groupStart` instead of `group_start`, `orLike` instead of `or_like`, and `$this->request->getVar()` instead of `$_GET`